# Take the values from the array with WebMethod

Tags: c#, webforms, webmethod

I have following jquery array, that takes the values from two columns from my table and show's their values:

```
$(function () {
             $('#myButton').on('click', function () {

                 var myCollection = [];

                 $('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                     var row = this;
                     var myObj = {

                         label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
                         opis: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))
                     };
                     myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;

                 });

                 console.log(myCollection)

                 function valuefromType(control) {
                     var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
                     switch (type) {
                         case "input":
                             return $(control).val();
                             break;
                         case "span":
                             return $(control).text();
                             break;
                         case "select":
                             return $(control).val();
                             break;
                     }
                 }

                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "FirstPage.aspx",
                     //data: { obj: myCollection },
                     data: JSON.stringify(myCollection),
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",

                     success: function (response) {
                         console.log(response);
                     },
                     error: function (response) {
                         console.log(response);
                     }
                 });
             });
         });
```

Name of the first column is 'label' and name of the second is 'opis' result of the array in console:

```
myCollection
(6) […]
​
0: Object { label: "1", opis: "Test1" }
​
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "Test2" }
​
2: Object { label: "3", opis: "Test3" }
​
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "1" }
​
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "Test5" }
​
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "Test6" }
​
length: 6
```

Values are taken with this button click:

```
<button id="myButton"  type="button">Save</button>
```

Ajax(status 200) takes and POST's the values correctly 
JSON:

```
0   {…}
label   1
opis    test1
1   {…}
label   2
opis    test2
2   {…}
label   3
opis    test3
3   {…}
label   5
opis    1
4   {…}
label   9
opis    test5
5   {…}
label   15
opis    test6
```

Can someone help me with the C# part ?
I need WebMethod to take the values from ajax so I can send it to the database, or just help me read the values in c#.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your ajax got parameter and value in data

```
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "FirstPage.aspx",
                 data: JSON.stringify({'omyCollection': myCollection}), // Check this call.
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",

                 success: function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                 }
             });
```

Create a model class with two properties: label,opis
Note: The properties should have the same names as the ajax array's properties.

```
public class myCollection
{
    public String label{ get; set; }
    public String opis{ get; set; }
}
```

Now create a WebMethod in codebehind with a parameter of type List< myCollection >:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string GetCollection(List<myCollection> omyCollection)
{     
    foreach (myCollection mycol in omyCollection)
    {  
        string id = mycol.label; //access label from myCol object
        string opis = mycol.opis;
        //do something
     }
     return "response";
}
```

Thanks.